# Formula/VBA - Application defined or object defined error

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a vba code to write a formula in determined cell on my sheet, but it doesn't work. What's wrong ? 'Cause, i really don't see what am i doing wrong in this code.

```
Range("BC" & ActiveCell.Row).Formula = "=IF($BB" & ActiveCell.Row & "=" & """" & "REVIEW" & """" & ";IF(ROW($BB" & ActiveCell.Row & ")<MAX(IF($BB:$BB=" & """" & "OK" & """" & ";$A:$A));IF(TODAY()-$AY" & ActiveCell.Row & ">=3;" & """" & "DROP" & """" & ";" & """" & "REVIEW" & """" & ");" & """" & "REVIEW" & """" & ");" & """" & """" & ")"
```

Comment: Are you sure you want $BB2 and then a number? if the row is 10 you'll get BB210

Comment: Pull that string into a local variable, `Debug.Print` the string, grab it from the immediate pane (Ctrl+G), paste it into an empty cell. Excel will tell you what's wrong with it, if it doesn't jump at you right away from the debug output.

Comment: @Brotato Sorry, i forgot to remove this $BB2, it's only, $BB. Anyway, still doesn't working

Comment: @MathieuGuindon the variable are debuging this: `=IF($BB2="REVIEW";IF(ROW($BB2)<MAX(IF($BB:$BB="OK";$A:$A));IF(TODAY()-$AY2>=3;"DROP";"REVIEW");"REVIEW");"")`

Comment: Ok now did you try using exactly that as an Excel formula? I suspect Excel isn't going to like the `MAX(FALSE)` bit (i.e. `IF($BB:$BB="OK";$A:$A)` looks like it's missing a parameter for `value_if_false`), assuming the list separator character (`;`) is correct.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon No, this formula in VBA are not working. But, if i write manually in any cell, 'cause i tested before to put in VBA, works.

Comment: change the `;` to `,` or use .FormulaLocal instead of .Formula.

Comment: ... and the `MAX(IF($BB:$BB="OK";$A:$A))` part tells me that should be .FormulaArray, not .Formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computer's use of a `;` as the regional list separator is fouling you up. VBA is very EN-US-centric so the [Range.Formula](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx)  and [Range.FormulaR1C1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213527.aspx) expect a comma (`,`) as the function's argument list separator.

```
Range("BC" & ActiveCell.Row).Formula = "=IF($BB" & ActiveCell.Row & "=" & """" & "REVIEW" & """" & ", IF(ROW($BB" & ActiveCell.Row & ")<MAX(IF($BB:$BB=" & """" & "OK" & """" & ", $A:$A)), IF(TODAY()-$AY" & ActiveCell.Row & ">=3, " & """" & "DROP" & """" & ", " & """" & "REVIEW" & """" & "), " & """" & "REVIEW" & """" & "), " & """" & """" & ")"
```

Alternately, [Range.FormulaLocal property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838851.aspx) or [Range.FormulaR1C1Local property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838568.aspx) can be used with your own semi-colon as the list separator.

```
Range("BC" & ActiveCell.Row).FormulaLocal = "=IF($BB" & ActiveCell.Row & "=" & """" & "REVIEW" & """" & ";IF(ROW($BB" & ActiveCell.Row & ")<MAX(IF($BB:$BB=" & """" & "OK" & """" & ";$A:$A));IF(TODAY()-$AY" & ActiveCell.Row & ">=3;" & """" & "DROP" & """" & ";" & """" & "REVIEW" & """" & ");" & """" & "REVIEW" & """" & ");" & """" & """" & ")"
```

Your doubling up double quotes within a quoted string is a bit verbose and xlR1C1 notation would save some steps. `TEXT(,)` is the same as `""` in a formula; each produces the same zero-length string.

```
Range("BC" & ActiveCell.Row).Formula = "=IF($BB" & ActiveCell.Row & "=""REVIEW"", IF(ROW($BB" & ActiveCell.Row & ")<MAX(IF($BB:$BB=""OK"", $A:$A)), IF(TODAY()-$AY" & ActiveCell.Row & ">=3, ""DROP"", ""REVIEW""), ""REVIEW""), TEXT(,))"
'.FormulaR1C1
Range("BC" & ActiveCell.Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC54=""REVIEW"", IF(ROW(R:R)<MAX(IF(C54:C54=""OK"", C1:C1)), IF(TODAY()-RC51>=3, ""DROP"", ""REVIEW""), ""REVIEW""), TEXT(,))"
```

The xlA1 and xlR1C1 formula rewrites above each produce the following when ActiveCell is on the second row.

```
=IF($BB2="REVIEW", IF(ROW($BB2)<MAX(IF($BB:$BB="OK", $A:$A)), IF(TODAY()-$AY2>=3, "DROP", "REVIEW"), "REVIEW"), TEXT(,))
```

As I mentioned in comments above, that formula would seem to be an array formula. In that case, use the .Formula comma based rewrite but change the Range.Formula property to [Range.FormulaArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Formulaarray).

Comment: Gratz on 100k by the way! :D (edit: whoops, that’s premature because so likes to round rep, but still!)

Comment: @Jeeped ++++ there you are , you deserve it :)

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks for giving so much to the community , you're mug will be on the way soon :D

Comment: @Jeeped the `Range.FormulaLocal` works to me ! Thank you very much !